# C Code compiles but does not ask for user input

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, cs50

I'm a beginner in C doing the harvard cs50x course and this code was written a lot of help but I still can't seem to figure out why it compiles on vscode but does not ask for text from the user.

The prompt is on writing a code that can estimate the difficulty of a text according to grade level based on a given equation that I have included below. Some of the comments include my previous mistakes so they are not descriptions that I purposely added.

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Declare variables to count letters, words, and sentences
    // Check if character is an alphabet
    // letter++
    // If character is not an alphabet or punctuation
    // word++
    // If character is punctuation
    // sentence++

    int count_letter = 0;
    int count_word = 1;
    int count_sentence = 0;
    string text = get_string("What is your chosen text?\n");

    int text_length = strlen(text);
    for(int i = 0; i < text_length; i++) // Run through the length of the text?
    {
        if(isalpha(text[i])) // check if alphabet
        {
            count_letter++; // count the number of letters in the text
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < text_length; i++)
    {
        if(isspace(text[i])) {
            count_word++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < text_length; i++)
    {
        // if(text[i]=="." || text[i]=="?" || text[i]=="!")
        if(text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '?' || text[i] == '!') {
            count_sentence++;
        }
    }
    // L = letters/word*100, S = sentence/word*100
    int L = count_letter / count_word * 100;
    int S = count_sentence / count_word * 100;

    // index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8
    int index = round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8);

    printf("%d\n", index);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What are you seeing?

Comment: You'll need to attend to the integer arithmetic. `double L = (double)count_letter / count_word * 100;` etc.

Comment: Run the program from the prompt, not from within VSCode. It'll prompt the user properly.

Comment: I haven't read the CS50 project description, but... instead of "sentences/words", it seems more reasonable to use "words/sentences"... More words/sentence would define more difficult text...

Comment: Thanks everyone! I have it running now and I've included your tips too!

Comment: Your code uses nonstandar features of CS50.   As homework code, it is both, untestable (we have not access to `string` type definition, or the file `"cs50.h"` content)  You say the code doen't ask for any input, so that, which is not shown affects the first statement you use in your code (the call to `get_string()`)  It's difficult to say without access to the implementation of `get_string`, the type `string` and/or the documentation of both)  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
// L = letters/word*100, S = sentence/word*100
    int L = count_letter / count_word * 100;
    int S = count_sentence / count_word * 100;
```

you are doing integer arithmetic, so you are dividing the number of letters by the number of words (the numer of letters is supposed to be larger) but the division is done as integers, so once multiplying it by 100 you will get no decimals (you will get a number ended in two final `00` digits)

you have a chance here, is to multiply first by 100, and then you will get the closest result as an integer and you will get decimals.

Another chance is to convert the numbers to floating point as soon as possible, as in:

```
// L = letters/word*100, S = sentence/word*100
     /* using a floating point literal forces the calculation to be done as real numbers */
    int L = 100.0 * count_letter   / count_word;
    int S = 100.0 * count_sentence / count_word;
```

or even better (get and use `double` floating point numbers all the time) after calculations:

```
// L = letters/word*100, S = sentence/word*100
     /* using a floating point number forces the calculation to be done as real numbers */
    double L = 100.0 * count_letter   / count_word;
    double S = 100.0 * count_sentence / count_word;
```

The data numbers continue to be integers, but as the first operation consists of multiplying a real number (the `100.0` floating point literal) the first product is calculating as floating point (the second argument, the first variable in the expression, is converted to `double` before doing the calculation, and the third, are both converted to `double` before doing the calculations) resulting in double precision values.

So finally you can show the result as a floating point number with:

```
    // index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8
    /* everything is calculated as floating point numbers (L and S have been defined as double above */
    double index = round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8);

    /* the formatting specifier must be g below, once index is floating point */
    printf("%g\n", index);
```